# Чутьё материала в значении прочувствование оного - ничего?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Пусть мы рассуждаем тут не о технических сложностях, тем не менее –
>   **чутьё материала** и подход к его обработке раскрывают нам немаловажные грани дарования мастера.

По смыслу, конечно, всё понятно, читатель не заблудится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://refdb.ru/look/2008159-p9.html

Материал и техника его обработки имеют очень большое значение в скульптуре. **Верное чутье материала,** умение найти соответствующую материалу идею и тему, или, наоборот, воплотить идею в подходящем материале — важный элемент дарования скульптора....

Comment: Спасибо за цитату!

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать, что скульптора отличало особое **чутьё по отношению к материалу**: либо он хорошо выбирал его по интуиции, либо к имеющемуся материалу относился с тонким пониманием. В исходном же варианте грамматически возможное сочетание "*чутьё материала*" наводит на мысль, будто оно непосредственно получено из странного выражения "*мастер чуял материал*", поэтому такое словосочетание воспринимается как вульгаризм..

Answer (score 0):

Чутье — способность распознавать, интуиция. Не есть прочувствование и не сочетается с родительным падежом (исключение: *чье*?)